# How do I hide the heap methods from the user when writing a priority queue?

Tags: go

I'm following [this code](https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/) to implement a priority queue. The thing I don't like is that when using it in the main method, the user has to call heap.Push and heap.Pop. It would make more sense to me to have my Priority queue contain a heap, rather than wrapping it in a heap. Am I thinking about this wrong, or does the example code show the right way to do it in Golang?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but if you want to implement a priority queue and have control over the API, you should create your own type and expose whatever you want to the outside world. Internally, you can use `PriorityQueue` if that does what you want it to do. Can you post some code to indicate what it is you want to implement?

Comment: `heap.Interface` docs: _... `Push` and `Pop` in this interface are for package `heap`'s implementation to call. To add and remove things from the heap, use `heap.Push` and `heap.Pop`._ It makes sense if you think about it. If you don't want to make use of package `heap`'s benefits, there's nothing wrong with implementing a priority queue yourself. As far as I can tell, it only provides efficient insertion/lookup due to its tree-based functionality. For example, it essentially takes your simple `Push` method and inserts it where it's necessary, so you need not do the same.

Comment: I think I managed to answer my own question. I created another type, RunePriorityQueue, which is a struct whos only member is a PriorityQueue. It also has Push and Pop, which just call heap.Push and heap.Pop on its memper PriorityQueue.

Comment: You're free to wrap the functionality using your own methods of course. You might have a private `priorityQueue` that does the work with `PriorityQueue` being the user-facing implementation with appropriate `Push` and `Pop` methods that call `heap.Push` and `heap.Pop` respectively.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a wrapper class which calls heap.Push and heap.Pop.

```
package huffman

import "container/heap"

type RunePriorityQueue struct {
    queue PriorityQueue
}

func (RunePriorityQueue) NewRunePriorityQueue() *RunePriorityQueue {
    newRPQ := new(RunePriorityQueue)
    heap.Init(&newRPQ.queue)
    return newRPQ
}

func (rpq *RunePriorityQueue) Push(item *Item) {
    heap.Push(&rpq.queue, item)
}

func (rpq *RunePriorityQueue) Pop() *Item {
    return heap.Pop(&rpq.queue).(*Item)
}
```